# Firebase authdata from third-party authentication is always null in mobile safari iOS8

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, firebase, firebase-security

I'm referencing "https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.1.2/firebase.js"

fb.onAuth is always returning authData null for mobile safari in iOS8. authData is not null on other desktop browsers and mobile chrome.

```
fb.onAuth(function(authData) {
  if (authData !== null) {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
    window.location.replace("<myappsurl>");
  } else {

  }
});
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually an issue related to mobile safari settings. If private browsing is enabled on mobile safari, authData will appear null.

Comment: A quick guess would be that localStorage and cookies are not allowed while using private browsing, which are required for firebase auth.